# i have added custom field to list_display but when add that field list_editable in django admin i get error:adminE121

Tags: django, django-admin

i have a method on model admin class that get data of reverse relation field on list_display but  when i add that field in list_editable as well i get  an error

```
<class 'app.admin.CustomerAdmin'>: (admin.E121) The value of 'list_editable[2]' refers to 'box_status', which is not an attribute of 'app.Customer'.
```

these is model admin class

```
@admin.register(Customer)
class CustomerAdmin(AbstractModelAdmin):
    class Media:

    list_display = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'stylist', 'box_schedule', 'drop_off_step', 
                    'box_status', 'age''created_at', 'payment_status']
    list_display_links = ('name', 'email')
    search_fields = ['name', 'email', 'id']
    list_editable = ['stylist', 'payment_status', 'box_status']
```

below is my box_status  method that is getting from related model field.

```
    def box_status(self, obj):
        det = list(obj.box.values_list('box_status', flat=True))
        return det
```

this works in list_display but system error in list_editable.

Answer (score 1):

For one, you are using method in list editable. Django only allows model fields to be edited in list_editable. Not 'returns' from methods.

Answer (score 0):

In list_editable you can specify only model fields.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable

Comment: i know it dear but i want to override the default behavior so any help please

Comment: Can you please explain why you need this?

Comment: i need this because one of my related model field is working in list display but what i want is that user can directly change related model field here on this page by making it editable.

Comment: I'm not sure, that I quite understand you, but maybe it helps you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline

Comment: thanks you! but  i reached the result that we can not add fields other then model fields in django list_editables.